# Filtering foreign key data by created_by field using Class-Based-View

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-views

This is my **models.py**

```
class InvoiceLine(AbstractSaleLine):
    invoice = models.ForeignKey('books.Invoice',
                                related_name="lines")
    name = models.ForeignKey('books.Item')
    tax_rate = models.ForeignKey('books.TaxRate')

    class Meta:
        pass

class Item(models.Model):
    item = models.CharField(max_length=255)   
    created_by = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="Item", default=1)
```

**views.py**

```
class InvoiceCreateView(generic.CreateView):
    template_name = "books/invoice_create_or_update.html"
    model = Invoice
    form_class = InvoiceForm
    formset_class = InvoiceLineFormSet
    success_url = reverse_lazy("books:invoice-list")
```

**forms.py**

```
class InvoiceLineForm(RestrictLineFormToOrganizationMixin,
                      ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = InvoiceLine
        fields = (
            "name",
            "tax_rate",
            "item_id"
        )
```

How do i filter Item the foreign key by field created_by using CBV? I am using CreateView.

Answer (score 0):

You can override `get_queryset`, to get current user use `self.request.user`. To filter by related model's field use [`__`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/db/queries/#lookups-that-span-relationships) notation:

```
class InvoiceCreateView(generic.CreateView):
    template_name = "books/invoice_create_or_update.html"
    model = InvoiceLine
    form_class = InvoiceForm
    formset_class = InvoiceLineFormSet
    success_url = reverse_lazy("books:invoice-list")

    def get_queryset(self):
        return InvoiceLine.objects.filter(name__created_by=self.request.user)
```

Comment: I have a model **InvoiceLine** which has field **name** having foreign key **Item**. i want to filter that model which has field **created_by**. This means if the user is selecting any item it should filter something like this `Item.object.filter(created_by==request.user)`. This is what i did in function based view.

Comment: @MikePinkman `InvoiceLine.objects.filter(name__created_by=self.request.user)` will filter InvoiceLine by item's `created_by`. If you need to list `Item` you should specify `model = Itme` in your view, and change `get_queryset` to this: `Item.objects.filter(created_by=self.request.user)`.

Answer (score 0):

You can override the [queryset](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/fields/#django.forms.ModelChoiceField.queryset) for the `ModelChoiceField` when the form is initialised:

```
class InvoiceLineForm(RestrictLineFormToOrganizationMixin, ModelForm):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        user = kwargs.pop('user')
        self.fields['item'].queryset = Item.objects.filter(created_by=user)

    class Meta:
        model = InvoiceLine
        fields = (
            "name",
            "tax_rate",
            "item"   # Note this should be `item` not `item_id`
        )
```

You then need to pass the `user` to the form [when you initialise the formset](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/forms/formsets/#passing-custom-parameters-to-formset-forms) - something like:

```
formset = formset_class(form_kwargs={'user': self.request.user})
```

Comment: I am getting this error. name 'request' is not defined in this line `formset = formset_class(form_kwargs={'user': **request**.user})`

Comment: You need to pass the correct request from the available context in your view - `self.request.user` if using a class based view.

Comment: self.request.user is also not working. I am getting **name 'self' is not defined** and could you please show me an example. how to do in my class based view.

Comment: Please edit your question to show us how you are currently initialising the form and the formset in your view.